# Using useEffect with async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using this code:

```js
useFocusEffect(
  useCallback(async () => {
    const user = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("user"));

    if (user.uid) {
      const dbRef = ref(dbDatabase, "/activity/" + user.uid);

      onValue(query(dbRef, limitToLast(20)), (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      });

      return () => {
        off(dbRef);
      };
    }
  }, [])
);
```

I'm getting this error:

> An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which
> is used for clean-up. It looks like you wrote 'useFocusEffect(async ()
> => ...)' or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately.

I tried to put everything inside an `async` function, but then the `off()` is not being called.

Comment: You aren't using `useEffect` in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `dbRef` variable outside the nested `async` function so your cleanup callback can reference it, and allow for the possibility it may not be set as of when the cleanup occurs.

Also, whenever using an `async` function in a place that doesn't handle the promise the function returns, ensure you don't allow the function to throw an error (return a rejected promise), since nothing will handle that rejected promise.

Also, since the component could be unmounted during the `await`, you need to be sure that the `async` function doesn't continue its logic when we know the cleanup won't happen (because it already happened), so you may want a flag for that (`didCleanup` in the below).

So something like this:

```
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        let dbRef;
        let didCleanup = false;
        (async() => {
            try {
                const user = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("user"));

                if (!didCleanup && user.uid) {
                    dbRef = ref(dbDatabase, "/activity/" + user.uid);

                    onValue(query(dbRef, limitToLast(20)), (snapshot) => {
                        console.log(snapshot.val());
                    });
                }
            } catch (error) {
                // ...handle/report the error...
            }
        })();
        return () => {
            didCleanup = true;
            if (dbRef) {
                off(dbRef);
            }
        };
    }, [])
);
```

Comment: @HTInvest - Sorry, I haven't used `useFocusEffect` (or React Native) and misread [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) (I did look at it, just not closely enough!). I've fixed the answer, thanks!